# Casting issue when rounding double values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, rounding

In my razor view i used following code to round the model value "Budget" to nearest integral value. The model value "Budget" is a `double?` value. But when assigning final value for `roundMyPrice` visual studio gives an error.

Why can't i use `double?` value as an argument? How can i overcome this problem?

```
@{
    double? budget = item.Budget;
    double? myPrice = budget / count;
    double roundMyPrice = Math.Round(myPrice, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```

Comment: is there really a `double?` data type?

Comment: @Stuart: `double?` is shorthand for `Nullable<double>`.

Answer (score 1):

`double?` (or `Nullable<double>`) can be `null`, remember it.

**Variant 1**

```
double? myPrice = budget / count;
double roundMyPrice;
if (myPrice.HasValue)
{
    roundMyPrice = Math.Round(myPrice.Value, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
else
{
    // value is not presented
}
```

**Variant 2**

MSDN: [GetValueOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx)

If `null` is 0 by your logic, you can use this code:

```
double? myPrice = budget / count;
double roundMyPrice = Math.Round(myPrice.GetValueOrDefault(), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: In this case, it would make more sense to check if `budget` has value.

Answer (score 0):

There's no overload for `double?` in `Math.Round` so you need to pass a `double` as parameter. Also you need to consider the case when your `double?` is `null`. Finally, you need to cast the result of `Math.Round` to `double?`.

```
double? budget = item.Budget;
double? myPrice = budget / count;
double? roundMyPrice = myPrice.HasValue ? (double?) Math.Round(myPrice.Value, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) : null;
```